# Getting error "io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 6203" when using redis cluster with Spring Data Redis in spring boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Spring data redis to connect to Redis Cluster.
when trying to trigger Redis Commands from application, it gives the following error

```
Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 6203 rg-69012fb7-7416-4876-8933-606a38ff54e7-0001-001.rg-69912fb7-7416-4876-8933-605a38ef54e7.vwvwdz.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:2660
```

As a solution for this, I tried configuring ClusterTopologyRefreshOption like following:

```
ClusterClientOptions clusterClientOptions = ClusterClientOptions.builder()
        .timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.enabled(Duration.ofSeconds(60L)))
        .topologyRefreshOptions(ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                .enablePeriodicRefresh(Duration.ofSeconds(60L)) // Refresh the topology periodically.
                .enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers() // Refresh the topology based on events.
                .build())
        .build();
LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
        .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60L))
        .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED) // Preferentially read data from the replicas.
        .clientOptions(clusterClientOptions)
        .build();
RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
redisClusterConfiguration.addClusterNode(new RedisNode(redisHost, redisPort));
redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);
return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration, clientConfig);
```

I get the same error i.e.

```
Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 6203 rg-69012fb7-7416-4876-8933-606a38ff54e7-0001-001.rg-69912fb7-7416-4876-8933-605a38ef54e7.vwvwdz.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com:2660
```

Any suggestion if I missed anything in this configuration?